# Copy Rows based on matches within columns

Tags: excel, vba

So i am looking to copy rows into a new sheets if they satisfy certain criteria. 
I am currently testing this out using 1 criteria as i suspect once i master this i will be able to apply multiple criteria using the And function.

The criteria is as follows. if the value in column i is equal to the negative value in column i then copy both rows into a new sheet. for example if Range("i5") = - Range("i20") then copy both rows into a new sheet.

However, i can't seem to copy the rows once my criteria is satisfied. See below

```
Sub test()

Dim n As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim CurrentRow As Long

n = Range("A8").End(xlDown).Row
CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1

For i = 8 To n
For j = 8 To n

If Range("i" & i) = -Range("i" & j) Then


Sheets("Sheet1").Range(CurrentRow & ":" & CurrentRow) = Sheets("Sheet2").Range(i & ":" & i)
CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & CurrentRow) = Range(j & ":" & j)
CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1

End If
Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub test()

Dim n As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim CurrentRow As Long
Dim Row1 As Range, Row2 As Range


n = Range("A8").End(xlDown).Row
CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1

For i = 8 To n
For j = 8 To n

If Range("i" & i) > 0 And Range("i" & i) = -Range("i" & j) Then

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(i & ":" & i).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(CurrentRow & ":" & CurrentRow)

CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(j & ":" & j).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & CurrentRow)

CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1

End If
Next j
Next i

End Sub
```